# Difference between GridSearch best_estimator_ and best_params_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I've been using grid search (scikit library) and random search to optimize my random forest for authorship attribution. However, I don't understand the difference between best_estimator_ and best_params_, they both give different parameters and I don't know which one I should use.

I have tried testing them both and I've noticed that best_params reaches better testing accuracy but it overfits more. I am not sure if that's the difference.

Comment: Can you share how you are calling the function (paste your code), as `best_estimator_` can change based on what you use for `refit` (`True` or `False`)

Comment: Agree with the other commenter that we need to see your code. And you probably know this but remember you don't want to use the best estimator from grid search beyond testing. Instead, train your final model on *all* your data (train, val and test), using the best params that you found.

Comment: Sure I use default version of refit which is True the code looks like this 
```
    rs = GridSearchCV(clf, hyper, verbose=2, n_jobs=3)
    search = rs.fit(x_train, y_train)
    return search
```
I then work with estimator which grid search returned to evaluate everything. However when I print out search.best_estimator_ and search.best_params_ they are different

Comment: That indeed shouldn't happen. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example, maybe using made up data (edit that into the question, not as a comment)? What parameters are different (it's not just that some aren't displayed, is it?)?

Comment: I apologize, I had my results mixed together (that had nothing to do with code). It does indeed return the same results.